# How to access child scope?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

In the below code, I'm trying to get a console log in the Directive (child scope),I need to get scope details.I tried adding a scope variable to the function in the directive also, but didn't work.

How can I fix this?

myDirective.html

```
<html ng-app="MyAppdr">
    <head>
      <script src="angular.js"></script>
      <script src="appdr.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="dirCtrl">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <employee-card></employee-card>
      <!--div employee-card></div>
      <div class="employee-card"></div--->
    </body>
<html>
```

employee_info.html

```
    <b>{{employee.name}}</b> - {{employee.job}}
    <br/><br/>
    <div ng-show='!!employee.followers'>
      followers
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='name in employee.followers'>{{name}}</li>
      </ul>
      <button ng-click="follow('Galaa')">follow</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

appdr.js

```
name="MyAppdr";
requires=[];

appdr=angular.module(name,requires);

appdr.controller("dirCtrl",function($scope){
    console.log("This is controller dirCtrl");
    $scope.employee={
      name:"subo",
      job:"cat",
      followers:["chin","adyakshaka","aluu"]
    }
    console.log("parent ",$scope);
    /*
    $scope.follow=function(name){
        $scope.employee.followers.push(name);
    }
*/
});
```

```
appdr.directive("employeeCard",function(){
    //$scope.employee={};
    console.log("child ",$scope);
    return{
      templateUrl:'employee_info.html',
      restrict:"AEC",
      //replace:true,
      controller:function($scope){
        $scope.follow=function(name){
            $scope.employee.followers.push(name);
        }

      },
      scope:true


    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `console.log()` inside the `controller` of the directive.

```
appdr.directive("employeeCard", function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'employee_info.html',
    restrict: "AEC",
    //replace:true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      console.log("child ", $scope);
      $scope.follow = function(name) {
        $scope.employee.followers.push(name);
      }
    },
    scope: true
  }
});
```

If you will have only one `employee` card on the page then keep `scope: true` else if you need to show multiple cards in the same page, use an isolated scope and pass it in the template.

```
appdr.directive("employeeCard", function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'employee_info.html',
    restrict: "AEC",
    //replace:true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      console.log("child ", $scope);
      $scope.follow = function(name) {
        $scope.employee.followers.push(name);
      }
    },
    scope: {
      employee: "="
    }
  }
});
```

And in the html use something like

```
<employee-card employee="employee"></employee-card>
```

Refer the documentation of directive [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive/)

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, using `scope: false` seems to be sufficient if you are not showing multiple cards in same page.

```
appdr.directive("employeeCard",function() {
  return  {
    scope: false,
    // other attributes
```

If you need to show multiple cards in same page, use isolated scope and pass in

```
appdr.directive("employeeCard",function() {
  return  {
    scope: {
      employee: '='
    },
    // other attributes

<employee-card employee="employee"></employee-card>
```